# Owin Hosting Start Self Host

Tags: c#, owin

In a console app you can start a owin host like this:

```
string url = "http://localhost:8080";
using (WebApp.Start(url))
{
      Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
      Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The line

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

stops the server stopping. How would I start the server within a class and stop it stopping? Would I do this?

```
    public bool keepHosting;
    public void Start()
    {
        using (WebApp.Start(serverUrl))
        {
            while (keepHosting)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not too sure what you're trying to do - what is going to trigger this (eg. start the application)? Whatever has the power to start something should probably also have the power to stop it - which isn't possible above. You probably need to call "Start" in the entry point to the application as a whole, and keep that part going instead.

Comment: Changed the code to be a little clearer. I just don't know how to keep the hosting process alive.

Comment: The `while` loop with `Console.ReadLine();` is something I usually do myself. Can't see why it won't work for you.

Comment: The hosting process will remain alive for however long your application is alive. So within the console app, it's alive because the ReadLine is waiting for input (so program still running). If you want to start the webapp but not manage it within this class, you will probably need to store the result of the WebApp.Start method, and implement the IDisposable pattern to call dispose against that for when your class is disposed.  It will be up to the caller to keep itself alive.

Comment: public IDisposable Start()
        {

          return  WebApp.Start(serverUrl);

        }

Comment: @PaulStanley yes that approach would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I think you could do it.

```
    public IDisposable Start()
    {
     return  WebApp.Start(serverUrl);
    }
```